# How to set array of pointers all to nullptrs in constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, initialization

```
class TrieNode {
public:
    TrieNode() : next{new TrieNode *[26]} {}
    TrieNode **next;
    string word;
};
```

I have to use raw pointers for this application, and I was wondering how I can set all of the 26 pointers to `nullptr` in the constructor? Would I have to loop over `next` and set each one individually or is there another faster way to do it?

Comment: You don't need dynamic allocation of the array here. `TrieNode *next[26]` is good. `std::array<TrieNode*, 26>` is better.

Answer (score 6):

You can perform [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> 3. if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
> 4. otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

And

> The effects of zero initialization are:
>
> - If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.

```
class TrieNode {
public:
    TrieNode() : next{new TrieNode *[26]()} {}
//                                      ^^  or use {} since C++11
    TrieNode **next;
    string word;
};
```

As the effect all the elements of the array would be initialized as null pointer.

Comment: I've used C++ for a few years now  and I've never heard of value-initialization. Is this a commonly known/used feature?

Comment: Oops, by that I mean, I've been using it, but I never knew that it makes all the pointers nullptr.

Comment: @user5965026 Yes it's an important feature, i.e. the difference between `new TrieNode *[26]` and `new TrieNode *[26]()`.

Comment: @user5965026 c++ is full of features, always take time to look up new features when a compiler version is updated. And keep up to data. E.g. if you've been using c++ for years why still use raw arrays like this instead of std::vector/std::array. 

What can help to keep up is to watch videos from ccpcon, like this excellent one from Jason Turner that gives an overview of c++ evolution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz5Qx18H6lg&t=686s